# Map step that involves subprocess with pipe fails in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My goal is to to read binary (gpg-encrypted) files on hdfs consisting of csv data. My approach -- following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765052/2708667) -- has been to define a Python function to read and decrypt a gpg file, yielding each line, and to apply this function as a `flatMap` to a parallel list of files.

Essentially, the Python function spawns a subprocess that reads the file using `hadoop` and pipes the result to `gpg` to decrypt. This works just fine when running Spark in local mode. However, running it distributed (`yarn-client`), a simple line count returns `0`, essentially because Python thinks the `stdout` pipe is always closed.

The issue seems to be that the subprocess involves a pipe between two commands. When I remove the latter (just a line count of the encrypted file), the line count matches what I get on command line. I've tried this multiple ways, all with the same result.

Here's the Python function:

```
import subprocess as sp

def read_gpg_file_on_hdfs(filename):
    # Method 1:
    p = sp.Popen('hadoop fs -cat {} | gpg -d'.format(filename), shell=True,
                 stdout=sp.PIPE)
    # Method 2:
    p1 = sp.Popen(['hadoop', 'fs', '-cat', filename], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    p = sp.Popen(['gpg', '-d'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()

    # Method 3:
    p = sp.Ppen('gpg -d <(hadoop fs -cat {})'.format(filename), shell=True,
                stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    for line in p.stdout:
        yield line.strip()
```

And here's the Spark command:

```
sc.parallelize(['/path/to/file.gpg']).flatMap(read_gpg_file_on_hdfs).count()
```

Now I know that PySpark uses pipes to communicate with Spark, but I don't follow the details and I don't know if this would affect what I'm trying to do. My question is whether there is a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Note that I'm using Spark 1.2.1 distributed (the latest release from MapR). Also, I considered using `binaryFiles`, but this would fail for large gpg files, which I sometimes encounter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `gpg` command is actually the issue. Presumably it's related to the details of how subprocesses are launched in local mode versus distributed, but in local mode the `homedir` of `gpg` is set correctly. But when launched in distributed mode, `homedir` was pointing to an incorrect directory and the second subprocess immediately failed. This error message didn't appear to be logged anywhere, so `stdout` was just returned as an empty string.