# Processing bzipped json file in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have about 200 files in S3, e.g., `a_file.json.bz2`, each line of these file is a record in JSON format but some fields were serialised by `pickle.dumps`, e.g. a `datetime` field. Each file is about 1GB after `bzip` compression. Now I need to process these files in Spark (pyspark, actually) but I couldn't even get each record out. So what would be the best practice here?

The `ds.take(10)` gives

```
[(0, u'(I551'),
 (6, u'(dp0'),
 (11, u'Vadv_id'),
 (19, u'p1'),
 (22, u'V479883'),
 (30, u'p2'),
 (33, u'sVcpg_id'),
 (42, u'p3'),
 (45, u'V1913398'),
 (54, u'p4')]
```

Apparently the splitting is not by each record.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue [reading gpg-encrypted files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765052/2708667). You can use `wholeTextFiles` as Daniel suggests, but you have to be careful when reading large files as the entire file will be loaded to memory before processing. If the file is too large, it can crash the executor. I used `parallelize` and `flatMap`. Maybe something along the lines of

```
def read_fun_generator(filename):
    with bz2.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()

bz2_filelist = glob.glob("/path/to/files/*.bz2")
rdd_from_bz2 = sc.parallelize(bz2_filelist).flatMap(read_fun_generator)
```

Comment: This works for me with slight modifications. I have to `yield pickle.load(f)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the input file-by-file (instead of line-by-line) via [`SparkContext.wholeTextFiles`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles). You can then use `flatMap` to uncompress and parse the lines in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is a problem caused by `pickle`. By looking at the file content after the compression, it is indeed

```
(I551
(dp0
Vadv_id
p1
V479883
p2
sVcpg_id
p3
V1913398
p4
```

which gives me trouble to parse. I know I can just `pick.load(file)` multiple times to get the objects out, but cannot find a quick solution in Spark where I can only access the loaded files line by line. Also, the records in this file have variable fields and lengths which makes it more difficult to hack.

I ended up re-generating these `bz2` files from the source because it is actually easier and faster. And I learnt that Spark and hadoop supports `bz2` compression perfectly so there is no additional action required.