# using wholeTextFiles in pyspark but get the error of out of memory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some files (part-00000.gz, part-00001.gz, part-00002.gz, ...) and each part is rather large. I need to use the filename of each part because it contains time stamp information. As I know, it seems that in pyspark only wholeTextFiles can read input as （filename, content）. However, i get the error of out of memory when using wholeTextFiles. So, my guess is that wholeTextFiles reads a whole part as content in mapper without partition operation. I also find this answer ([How does the number of partitions affect `wholeTextFiles` and `textFiles`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906583/how-does-the-number-of-partitions-affect-wholetextfiles-and-textfiles)). If so, how can i get the filename of a rather large part file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `wholeTextFiles` tries to read the entire file into a single RDD. You're better off reading the file line-by-line, which you can do simply by writing your own generator and using the `flatMap` function. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191680/2708667) of doing that to read a gzip file:

```
import gzip
def read_fun_generator(filename):
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()

gz_filelist = glob.glob("/path/to/files/*.gz")
rdd_from_bz2 = sc.parallelize(gz_filelist).flatMap(read_fun_generator)
```

Comment: I am working in amazon s3. Does glob.glob work? Your answer also seems to read all lines of a file given the filename(part-00000). Should I replace bz2.open with sc.textfile

Comment: I not only want to use filename but also the content. It seems that you answer still read a whole part file in a RDD line-by-line.

Comment: You'll have to tweak this code to do exactly what you want. The glob command is really just to get a list of file names, which is saved to `bz2_filelist`. The idea is to create an RDD of filenames (which is what `parallelize` does) then for each filename read every line in that file. Note that you have access to the filename in this generator. For example, you can do `yield filename + "|" + line.strip()` if you want to prepend the filename to every line.